# Is it possible to modify the structure of a 3D model at runtime in ARCore?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, arcore

I'm building an android app in Android Studio and Kotlin that implements ARCore to render 3D models of bar charts. I need to render these models based on real time data obtained from an API, but I don't know if there is a way to modify a 3D model struture at runtime in order to make the bar chart reflect the real time data.

I'm aware of the possibility to render 3D models at runtime using Sceneform, as well as changing texture, but this doesn't seem to help me with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth considering whether you can use the animation functionality available for renderables to meet your needs - i.e. design your bar graph so that the changes you want are part of the animation design.

This will allow you use Sceneform's built in animationm support: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/animation/overview-enable-animations

Like 3D models the animations are created in advance and imported into the project when you are building it.

If your models are going to be relatively simple, you can also create simple renderables at runtime using ViewRenderable.builder() - this allows you refer to a layout or to a view created programatically where you can set the height for a bar in a graph for example. More info here: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/create-renderables